# My transcripts are not an accurate indication of my academic ability

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor

Can the absence of an official academic adviser in the department at which I finished my undergraduate studies be used in my graduate application to justify some deficiencies in my undergraduate grades transcripts?

Comment: Without knowing the whole story, generally no, the admission committee looks for **reasons to enroll you**, not the reasons for your bad grades. If you have bad grades due to the lack of an adviser, then you better have other evidence to show your true academic ability. E.g. exceptional TOEFL and GRE, or a steady improvement in grades from freshmen through senior year would be ideal.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight - you really should be submitting this as an answer. It responds to the question perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you can use percentiles for your grades. That is a more fair system. What kind of deficiencies are we talking about?

Comment: @Penguin_Knight: Good TOEFL and GRE scores are unlikely to make up for a sufficiently bad transcript.

Comment: Do most PhD applicants have official academic advisors?  I would find that _very_ surprising.

Comment: @Trylks Deficiencies such as taking some advanced courses before their unofficial prerequisites (the devised plan doesn't mention the dependency), or taking a course with a lecturer who arranges exam dates that conflicts with other courses from other departments (happens a lot)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The lack of an official advisor is most unlikely to be of any benefit as an excuse for not doing well in classwork. Presumably you have a common core of classes in your major, and you'd better have a good explanation for any significant deficits in those courses. The lack of an advisor might have led to poor course choices in electives, but you could have ended up taking the same courses even if you had had an advisor. Moreover, your advisor didn't take your classes for you; he didn't do your homework or take your tests or complete your projects for you. Ultimately, **you** are responsible for your performance as a student.

Comment: I also can't help but think that giving this as an explanation is probably worse than not addressing it at all.  One of the key things programs expect students to develop is independence, the ability to learn things on their own and to take responsibility for their own education.  Even if it is unfair, I think this makes "someone else did a bad job of telling me what to do" a uniquely bad excuse.